# why a website for buying bitcoins is asking for my CVC code

Tags: security, coinbase.com, bitcoin-core-accounts

I am trying to create an account on coinbase to buy bitcoins (in france). But coinbase is asking for my cvc number while creating the account, not for a purchase.
I am afraid for security issues, as I have been told to not give the cvc to anyone.
Can any one explain please?
Is there a way to avoid that?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: CoinBase is a trusted website, if you give them your CVC and your credit card number and its expiry date, they should be able to withdraw money from your credit card worth 10000 Dollars if they want. But I've never sesn someone whose money is stolen by CoinBase. If you have question, ask it to CoinBase support, https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/emails/new , it may take up to two weeks to get a response. Good luck.